# Extra column with different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have SQL script and try to add extra column with different conditions but cant get it to work.

```
Select
PUB_Name As 'Pub Name'
,SUM(PUB_Collected) AS Collected 
,Sum(PUB_Loyalty) As SumLoyalty 
,(CASE WHEN SUM(PUB_Collected)>0 THEN (SUM(PUB_Loyalty)/SUM(PUB_Collected))ELSE NULL END) AS 'Percentage'
,SUM(PUB_Lodged_To_Till) As SumLodged 
,Sum(PUB_Paid_Out) As SumPaidOut 
,SUM(PUB_Lodged_To_Till) - Sum(PUB_Paid_Out) As 'Profit/Lose' 
,SUM(PUB_Lodged_To_Till) - SUM(PUB_Paid_Out) - SUM(PUB_Loyalty) As 'Profit/Lose + Loyalty' 
FROM [MattPubsDB].[dbo].[PUBRecords] 
WHERE PUB_Date >= '2015-03-01'AND PUB_Date < '2015-06-01' 
Group By PUB_Name
```

I want to get this column:

```
,SUM(PUB_Lodged_To_Till) - SUM(PUB_Paid_Out) - SUM(PUB_Loyalty) As 'Profit/Lose + Loyalty 2nd'
```

with differed WHERE:

```
WHERE PUB_Date >= '2015-01-01'AND PUB_Date < '2015-06-01'
```

I will be grateful for any help as I just start learn SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to use conditional aggregation, and this will affect all your aggregations.  The query will look like:

```
Select PUB_Name As `Pub Name`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PUB_Date >= '2015-03-01'AND PUB_Date < '2015-06-01'  THEn PUB_Collected ELSE 0 END) AS Collected, 
       . . .
       SUM(CASE WHEN PUB_Date >= '2015-01-01'AND PUB_Date < '2015-06-01'
                THEN COALESCE(PUB_Lodged_To_Till, 0) - COALESCE(PUB_Paid_Out, 0) - COALESCE(PUB_Loyalty, 0) 
                ELSE 0
           END) As `Profit/Lose + Loyalty 2nd`

FROM [MattPubsDB].[dbo].[PUBRecords] 
Group By PUB_Name;
```

I would suggest that you change the column aliases so they do not need to be escaped (no spaces, for instance).  If you don't want to change the name, then use back ticks.  Although single quotes are allowed, they tend to lead to confusion, because they are not allowed around column aliases anywhere else.

Comment: I was try to use this code but it's still not solve problem. You put only one column with name "Profit/Lose + Loyalty 2nd" but You not put first column with different conditions. When I was copy line with  "Profit/Lose + Loyalty 2nd" and change name column and date range I have error "Incorrect syntax near 'SUM'".

Comment: Sorry my error I was forget to put ",". Can You let me know how to sort line with Percentage as there is already one CASE.

Comment: @Hateusz . . . You can use `order by <column alias>`, where the alias is defined in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Sorry again, I'm not make this clear I don't know how to wrote line with percentage column. There is already CASE in it and 3 different SUM. Do I have to put another CASE (with range of dates) for each SUM?

Comment: @Hateusz . . . You need a new `case`, *inside* the `sum()`:  `(case . .. then sum(case . . . end) else sum(case . .. end) end)`.